# ajax variable to php wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, jquery

Get the value of variable "value"

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("ordrNum",function(value,element){
     var isExist=false;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        async: false,
        data : "action=" + value,
        url  : ajaxurl,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
    //  document.writeln("test");
    //alert(data["order_no"]);
        //console.log(data["order_no"]);
        //   if (data["order_no"] >0) {
            //  isExist=true;
        //  } 
        }
    });
    //console.log(isExist);

    return isExist;//true;

},"This order number does not exist");
```

this is in validateForm.js under my wordpress plugin. i want to get the value of "VALUE" which is passed on action.  i want to transfer it to database to check if theres an existing data.

Comment: Well, that's a job for the script you're passing the data to, wouldn't you agree? Simply check for '$_POST["action"]' in the called script and you should be fine, right?

Comment: where can i  put '$_POST["action"]' ? and how to get it when it is in other folder

Comment: $_POST is a PHP superglobal. It is passed to the called script and can be checked there. But before we go there, you need to make sure, that the AJAX call actually works right. Have the called script output some content and output that either by alert or by HTML.

Comment: but then its a wordpress site. theres some things to be considered. like passing an ajax to handler which is the admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

the "data" setting has to set as follows :

```
$.ajax({
   ....
   data : {name:value},
   ...
});
```

You do not use = sign.

In your case it will be

```
data : {action:value},
```

Comment: and how will i use "data : {action:value}," so that i can access it from other source file. im using wordpress plugin